# Replace image by standard image on 404

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop over a set of images with the same class and attach the error handler to them so that on error I replace the image with a standard image by `$(this).attr('src', 'img path');` I am placing this `.each()` in the end of `document.ready()`. The loop iterates correctly, however `.error()` is not firing although I have a 404 Error. I tried `.click()` and alert to see what happens instead, and the alert popped up. How can I solve this so that `.error()` gets fired?

```
$('img.thumbnail-img').each(function(index, element)
{
    $(element).error(function()
    {
        load_thumbnails_error('img', this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you check your console (in developer tools)?  I think the problem is in `load_thumbnails_error` not in `.error`

Comment: Try seeing if the onload event fires instead. Based on a quick google search, it seems like it sometimes would call the onload event, on some browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/error/):

> The event handler must be attached before the browser fires the error event, which is why the example sets the src attribute after attaching the handler. Also, the error event may not be correctly fired when the page is served locally; error relies on HTTP status codes and will generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file: protocol.

If I understood this, it means if you execute your `.each` loop in the `$(document).ready` function all images has their error already fired.

Comment: Like it is described in this documentation. I would try it before the browser renders the html.

Comment: Look here: also a [good tutorial](http://www.paulund.co.uk/handle-image-loading-errors-with-jquery)